# Can I set the default Chatter reply email to be set depending on a picklist choice?

Tags: chatter

We are working with the Case Object and our user would like to set the default from address when they reply to someone in chatter to be from a certain email address which correlates to a case type which is in a field picklist.

For example, if the case type is "Ask the Library" the default email address when sending a reply through chatter should be "askthelibraryaquestion@XXXX.com"

Any way to do this?